# System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes missing characters after string conversion

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, sockets

I'm converting a json string to bytes array to send it through socket.

This is what I do:

```
byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
mySocket.Send(byData);
```

It's a normal Json string, not even that long. But when I receive the string on the client, it arrives truncated.

Example:

I send the string 
-command [{"ID":2821},{"ID":2823},{"ID":2827},{"ID":2829} (many more records here)] which will be the string variable "Data" in the code shown above.

and I get half of it, truncated at the 1021th characther.

Is that something about byte conversion limit?

What's going on?

EDIT:

The receiving code:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                streamWriter.WriteLine(msg);
                streamWriter.Flush();

                // Use the following code to send bytes
                byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                if(m_clientSocket != null){
                    m_clientSocket.Send (byData);
                }
```

Which truncates data at the bydata conversion.

Moreover the data is being sent 1023 bytes each time, resulting in multiple truncated strings which compose the big one.

Do I need to recompose the string by myself or there is another way

Comment: See the docs for `Send`.  It might not send all of the bytes.

Comment: Try debugging. What is the length of `byData` after the conversion? Is `byData` truncated? If yes, `GetBytes` has some limit. If no, the socket has a limit.Its more likely the socket. 1021 is very close to 1024 (1K).

Comment: Show us your receive code...

Comment: Neither Encoding.GetBytes nor Socket.Send have any undocumented limits, but as @SLaks suggested and the docs mention: *In nonblocking mode, Send may complete successfully even if it sends less than the number of bytes in the buffer. It is your application's responsibility to keep track of the number of bytes sent and to retry the operation until the application sends the bytes in the buffer.* Check the return value to see how many bytes were actually sent

Comment: When you're working with TCP sockets, the abstraction is streams of bytes - not *messages*. It's *your* responsibility to implement messaging if that's what you want. Which is a long way of saying that calls of `Send` at one end are *not* guaranteed to match up 1-1 with calls of `Receive` at the other end.

Comment: The "Receiving" code in your edit only seems to be more sending code (first by writing to a network stream, then by an explicit `Send` call)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right, but that's what sends the code to the client. The client receives just the truncated string so I need to either debug what happens before or to rebuild the full string once I receive the various string parts.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just ignore the return value of `Send` - it tells you how much data was actually sent. It is your responsibility to issue another `Send` with the remaining data.

And of course, the same applies on the other end - `Receive` will return you how much data was actually read.

Another thing to keep in mind is that TCP works with streams of data, not messages. If you need to send messages, you need your own message framing (for example, prefixing the data with their length so that you know when the message ends).

As a side-note, I'd avoid using `Encoding.ASCII` - it throws away any characters not in the 7-bit ASCII character set. `Encoding.UTF8` will behave the same for ASCII data, but it will also correctly handle anything that's *not* ASCII. The only drawback is that you can no longer rely on a 1:1 mapping between characters and bytes.

If you don't know exactly what you're doing, you want to avoid dealing with low level networking like this - TCP is still too low for most applications. I strongly suggest trying something like WCF or Lidgren instead. If you insist on using raw TCP, let me at least point you to a TCP client-server sample I made - https://github.com/Luaancz/Networking. The second part should fit you well enough. Note that this still ignores most of error handling, but otherwise handles TCP right - although I have to stress that it's still a work in progress. Use it as an inspiration, not as production-ready code.